# Ms Access 2010- Show Current day +- 6 days

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to show **Current day +- 6 days** ( Last week, Current week ) on a Form so, for example, Todays date is 18th, Friday, the code should show

```
18 Friday,
19 Saturday,
20 Monday,
21 Tuesday,
22 Wednesday,
23 Thursday

And the previous week with days
11,12,13,14,15,16,17
```

**What I have tried is the following which displays current date and day**

```
'Define the variables
Dim MyDay As Integer, MyMonth As Integer, MyYear As Integer, TheDate As Date, _
TheDayOfWeek As Integer, DayStr As String

'Convert the day of the current Date to a number
MyDay = Day(Date)

'Get the Month of the current Date
MyMonth = Month(Date)

'Get the Year of the current Date
MyYear = Year(Date)

'Convert the three above numbers to a date
TheDate = MyMonth & "/" & MyDay & "/" & MyYear

'Determine the day of the week
TheDayOfWeek = Weekday(TheDate)

'Assign a weekday name to the number
If TheDayOfWeek = 1 Then DayStr = "Sunday"
If TheDayOfWeek = 2 Then DayStr = "Monday"
If TheDayOfWeek = 3 Then DayStr = "Tuesday"
If TheDayOfWeek = 4 Then DayStr = "Wednsday"
If TheDayOfWeek = 5 Then DayStr = "Thursday"
If TheDayOfWeek = 6 Then DayStr = "Friday"
If TheDayOfWeek = 7 Then DayStr = "Saturday"

MsgBox DayStr & MyDay
```

Comment: Look at the `DateAdd` function to do this in a simple loop, and `Format(myDate, "dddd")` to get the weekday name.

Comment: You extract the year, month, and day values from `Date()`, and then use them to load a Date/Time variable `TheDate`.  That will give you the same value as `Date()` ... seems like you're making it unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use WeekdayName to get the name of the day.

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = -6 To 6
    MsgBox CStr(DateAdd("d", i, Date)) & " " & WeekdayName(Weekday(DateAdd("d", i, Date)))
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `DateAdd("d",x,MyDate)` to get a date that is `x` days away from `MyDate` (x can be negative).

Use `Format(MyDate,"d dddd")` to format the date the way you have in your example.